# Не работает вложенный цикл. Котлин

Tags: kotlin, for

не совсем понимаю как работают вложенные циклы, у меня есть задача, нужно объединить два массива в map с помощью цикла for, в моем коде вложенный цикл не работает, выходит только так {KG=+98, RU=+98, USA=+98, TR=+98}

```
var myMap: MutableMap<String, String>? = null

fun main(){

    val names = arrayOf("KG","RU", "USA", "TR")

    val codes = arrayOf("+996", "+7", "+1", "+98")

    myMap = mutableMapOf()

    for (name in names) {
        for (code in codes){
            myMap!![name] = code
        }
    }
    println(myMap)
    println(myMap!!["KG"])

}
```

Comment: Я что-то не могу понять, а что сделать-то Вы пытаетесь? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример того, что должна сделать Ваша программа, если она будет написана правильно?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov да она работает но не так как мне нужно, а мне нужно из двух массивов сделать map, чтобы ключ был с первого массива, а значение со второго

Comment: я понимаю, что она работает. Но Вы в вопросе не указали, как она ДОЛЖНА работать. Даже после Вашего комментария задачу можно по-разному интерпретировать. Фактически, в вопросе не хватает строки вида: _А должно быть так: {KG=+996, RU=+7, USA=+1, TR=+98}_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё у вас работает так, как вы и написали: каждому имени (`name`) последовательно ставятся в соответствие все коды (`code`), а сохраняется, т.е. ничем не замещается, последний код.

Пример вашей логики на js:

```js
names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
codes = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];

obj = {};

for (let name of names) {
    for (let code of codes) {
        obj[name] = code;
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Вместо этого вам нужно ставить в соответствие только элементы с одинаковым индексом, т.е.:

```
for (i in names.indices) {
    myMap!![names[i]] = codes[i];
}
```

Пример работы новой логики на js:

```js
names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
codes = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
obj = {};

for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    obj[names[i]] = codes[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```